# Is it possible to change brush size options in Aviary Image Editor (Web SDK)?

Tags: adobecreativesdk

I'm implementing the Image Editor in a web project, and can't find in the documentation how to change the brush sizes available in the UI (for the Draw tool).

For our application, even the smallest brush size from the default set is way too big for the drawing operation being performed.